# Finding min values in a 3D array across one axis and replacing the non-corresponding values in another 3D array with 0 without loops in python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, min, substitution

Let's say we have two 3D arrays, A(x,y,z) and B(x,y,z) that x,y,z  are dimensions. I want to identify all the minimum values across the z-axis in the A array and then based on those values and their indices choose the corresponding values in the B, keep them and replace other values with zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of it a little differently. Finding the locations of the minima in `A` is straightforward:

```
ind = np.expand_dims(np.argmin(A, axis=2), axis=2)
```

You can do one of the following things:

1. Simplest: create a replacement of `B` and populate the relevant elements:

   ```
    C = np.zeros_like(B)
    np.put_along_axis(C, ind, np.take_along_axis(B, ind, 2), 2)
   ```
2. Same thing, but in-place:

   ```
    values = np.take_along_axis(B, ind, 2)
    B[:] = 0
    np.put_along_axis(B, ind, values, 2)
   ```
3. Convert the index to a mask:

   ```
    mask = np.ones(B.shape, dtype=bool)
    np.put_along_axis(mask, ind, False, 2)
    B[mask] = 0
   ```

You can replace the calls to `take_along_axis` and `put_along_axis` with suitable indexing expressions. In particular:

```
indx, indy = np.indices(A.shape[:-1])
indz = np.argmin(A, axis=-1)
```

The examples above then transform into

1. New array:

   ```
    C = np.zeros_like(B)
    C[indx, indy, indz] = B[indx, indy, indz]
   ```
2. In-place:

   ```
    values = B[indx, indy, indz]
    B[:] = 0
    B[indx, indy, indz] = values
   ```
3. Masked:

   ```
    mask = np.ones(B.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[indx, indy, indz] = False
    B[mask] = 0
   ```